# How can printed value JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Please see my full json in the here: http://jsfiddle.net/D6fTZ/ and what that i want. how is for this json code put each reunits.reun in tooltip on each name_re? Like:

i can use this new JSON (if above JSON not work for what that i want. how can done it with this JSON): http://pastebin.com/TvcyjykR

**"name_re": "11"** =user should has this tooltip for it name_re(11)=> **11 11**
**"name_re": "11"** =user should has this tooltip for it name_re(11)=> **666666666 99999 777777 1221**
**"name_re": "12121112"** =tooltip for name_re(12121112)=> **55555 00000000 222222222 333333333**

How can fix it?

My try(don't work true):

```
$.each(data.reunits, function (index, value) {
    $('#residence_name').append('<div class="tool_tip"><div class="tooltip"><ul class="li_show"></ul></div><div class="tooltip_hover" style="font-weight: bold; padding: 5px 0 0 0; cursor: pointer;" id="' + value.residence[0].hotel_id + '">' + value.residence[0].name_re + '</div></div>');
    tool_tip();

    $.each(value.reun, function (index2, value2) {
        $('#residence_name .li_show').append('<li>' + value2.name + '</li>');
        tool_tip();
    });

});
```

Comment: just to be sure, you want a list of residences, with reunits names as tooltip?

Comment: Moreover, seeing your tool_tip() function, you can call it once, after both $.each. (and please put style tag in the a css) (and you don't need to use string+jsonparse, you can use a direct json object directly {[like: this]}. but that's a moot point for a fiddle).

Comment: @roselan - Do you can give me example in fiddle ffrom my code?

Comment: check the fiddle at the bottom of my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are adding each value to `li_show`. so it dont add just one,it adds each of class that using `li_show` class. So maybe u can change the class name with uniq names or better to use id for each value. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/D6fTZ/2/

```
$.each(data.reunits, function (index, value) {
    $('#residence_name').append('<div class="tool_tip"><div class="tooltip"><ul class="li_show" id="li_show'+index+'"></ul></div><div class="tooltip_hover" style="font-weight: bold; padding: 5px 0 0 0; cursor: pointer;" id="' + value.residence[0].hotel_id + '">' + value.residence[0].name_re + '</div></div>');

    $.each(value.reun, function (index2, value2) {
        $('#residence_name #li_show'+index+'').append('<li>' + value2.name + '</li>');

    });
    tool_tip();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a version that works:

```
$.each(data.reunits, function (index, value) {

    var $object = $('<div class="tool_tip"><div class="tooltip"><ul class="li_show"></ul></div><div class="tooltip_hover" style="font-weight: bold; padding: 5px 0 0 0; cursor: pointer;" id="' + value.residence[0].hotel_id + '">' + value.residence[0].name_re + '</div></div>');

    $.each(value.reun, function (index2, value2) {
        $('.li_show', $object).append('<li>' + value2.name + '</li>');
    });

    $('#residence_name').append($object);

});

tool_tip();
```

the problem you have is that you do the second append to '#residence .li_show'. this means you will add to **all** of them in the page, not the one linked to the residence handled in the loop. What I do is a variable in which the reuns are put, hence isolating them from the main page, and adding them once.

[clean jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/D6fTZ/5/)